# Change radio button outer border color and thickness

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change 2 radio buttons border color and border thickness but for some reason it is not doing anything.

Here is my code

```css
input[type='radio']:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  border: none;
}

input[type='radio']:checked:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 2.7px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f07f09;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  border: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  border-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: solid 3px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:before {
  border-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="contact-option" id="1" class="otp-text-gap" [(ngModel)]="contact" value="cell" (change)="changeOTPChannel()"><span class="otp-channel-text">Cell number</span>
<input type="radio" name="contact-option" id="2" class="otp-text-gap" [(ngModel)]="contact" value="email" (change)="changeOTPChannel()"><span class="otp-channel-text">Email</span>
```

Comment: Please define 'not doing anything'. If I run the code, I can see some changed styling, but I am not sure what's expected.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=input%3A%3Abefore

Comment: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2014/06/24/pseudo-element-input.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are a few things which you should keep in mind, pseudo-classes are not supported by input types
- you should not add an id as a number

In this below example I have used the label to trigger onchange for radio

```css
input[type='radio']{
  display:none;
}

input[type='radio'] + label{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label:after {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f07f09;
    content: "";
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
    content: "";
    border-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: solid 3px;
    width: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="contact-option" id="one" class="otp-text-gap" [(ngModel)]="contact" value="cell" (change)="changeOTPChannel()"><label for="one" class="otp-channel-text">Cell number</label>
<input type="radio" name="contact-option" id="two" class="otp-text-gap" [(ngModel)]="contact" value="email" (change)="changeOTPChannel()"><label for="two" class="otp-channel-text">Email</label>
```